# Listening to multiple UDP ports with Asio

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, boost-asio

I am trying to receive a message sent over UDP to one of four ports chosen randomly at the start of the application sending the data. This is the code I currently have, but no data is ever received on any of the ports. I cannot change it to use a single port, as it is not my own program and I do not have access to the source.

```
using boost::asio::ip::udp;

static char *port[] = {"54997", "34997", "57997", "58997"};

std::vector<udp::socket> sockets;
boost::asio::io_service io_service;

void getsockets()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        sockets.emplace_back(udp::socket(io_service));
        boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint local(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::any(), (unsigned short)strtoul(port[i], NULL, 0));
        sockets.back().open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());
        sockets.back().bind(local);
    }
    io_service.run_one();
}

int main()
{
    getsockets();
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            while (sockets[i].available() > 0)
            {
                boost::array<char, 128> recv_buf;
                boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint server;
                int len = sockets[i].receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf), server);
                std::cout.write(recv_buf.data(), len);
            }
            io_service.run_one();
        }
    }

    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

If my code seems fine, it could be my misunderstanding of the original receiver which is written in C#; a language I do not have much knowledge of. I do have the source of that, if it would help.

Comment: Just a guess, but the docs say `run_one` only runs "at most one handler", and it blocks. Could it be blocking waiting on a single port and missing events on other ports? There is a `poll` method that is non-blocking, and a `run` method that while blocking will run multiple handlers. (I'm not quite sure what a handler is in this context though).

Comment: I just tried replacing run_one with poll, and it didn't change anything. Run is for an asynchronous program and has to have event handlers set up. It essentially is just a blocking version of run_one() from what I understand.

Comment: Why have the ports as strings in the first place?

Comment: @EJP I've been messing around with it, if I get it working like this I'll change their type.